# SQL query for key and value

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I need to write a query that does the following. After searching various forums I see "PIVOT" is one of the ways to implement this. I am still trying to write an query using PIVOT but in the meantime can anyone suggest if there is any other alternate way to do the same?

```
TABLE T1

s_ID | a_ID
------------
 1   |  a1
------------
 2   |  a2
------------

 TABLE T2
a_ID | Key | Value
a1   | k1  | v1
a1   | k2  | v2
a1   | k3  | v3
a2   | k1  | v1
a2   | k2  | v2
a2   | k4  | v4
```

OUTPUT from query expected:

```
s_ID | a_ID | k1 | k2 | k3 | k4
---------------------------------
 1   | a1   | v1 | v2 | v3 |
---------------------------------
 2   | a2   | v1 | v2 |    | v4
```

Comment: You gotta use `PIVOT` or subquery. But `PIVOT` is the right way.

Comment: I would use conditional aggregation.  However, I suspect that you might want *dynamic* columns and that requires PL/SQL.

Comment: @FelyppOliveira: Do you know if Pivot will allow me to take care of dynamic key value? All the examples that I have seen shows constant key and values

Comment: `PIVOT` requires constant keys...

Comment: @FelyppOliveira: Will subquery work for dynamic keys? if subquery is not the option then writting PL/SQL is the only option?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Yes it is dynamic keys..do you have any pointers or similar example that you can point me to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use conditional aggregation

```
select s_id,t1.a_id, max(case when key='k1' then value end),
max(case when key='k1' then value end),
max(case when key='k2' then value end),
max(case when key='k3' then value end) from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.a_ID=t2.a_ID
 group by s_id,t1.a_id
```

Comment: @user3384231 then you have to use dynamic query

Comment: What do u mean by dynamic query? is it PL/SQL?

Comment: @user3384231 yes

Comment: I am trying to see if your query can work. Will your query throw an error if the key is not found? Can I somehow set "null" if the key not found?

Comment: @user3384231 if key column is avail then no error but if key column is not avail then it will throw error so column name is important

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189944/discussion-between-user3384231-and-zaynul-abadin-tuhin).

Comment: We went with your solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative solution but can be useful for you or someone else.

You need to `PIVOT` dynamic data, but Oracle can't do it nowadays in a single SQL query, only for static keys. So let's assign static keys for your dynamic keys.

```
with

-- your key/value data table
tmp_data(fk_id, key_name, key_value) as 
(
  select 1, 'a', '000' from dual union 
  select 1, 'b', '111' from dual union 

  select 2, 'a', '222' from dual union 
  select 2, 'c', '333' from dual union 

  select 3, 'a', '444' from dual union 

  select 4, 'c', '555' from dual union 
  select 4, 'd', '666' from dual 
),

-- a map of static keys for your dynamic keys
tmp_static(fk_id, key_name, key_num) as 
(
  select 
    0, -- just to union the data later
    key_name, -- your dynamic key
    row_number() over(order by key_name) -- our static key
  from tmp_data 
  group by key_name
)

-- here we get a header row
select *
from tmp_static
pivot
(
  max(key_name)
  for(key_num) in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12) -- static keys expected at most
)

union 

-- here we get data rows
select *
from
(
  select 
    t1.fk_id,
    t1.key_value,
    t2.key_num
  from tmp_data t1
  inner join tmp_static t2 on 1=1
    and t2.key_name = t1.key_name
)
pivot
(
  max(key_value)
  for(key_num) in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12) -- static keys expected at most
)
;
```

The result is the following:

[image: result]

As you can see in the result and in the SQL the first row actually contains the name of your dynamic keys, cause we couldn't map them in the `PIVOT` before hand. The other rows are your data.

There are lots of additional columns without any value. It's because we mapped your dynamic keys to sequential numbers starting on 1 to the number of distinct keys in your table. But we don't know this number before hand to write in the query, so the best option was to assume a limit number that will never be reach.

As you can see in my query, I assumed that the max number of keys for a same fk_id is 12, but you can always be sure of how much columns have data looking in the header row how much columns has names. Your applications should handle properly this header row and these empty columns.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. I cannot run multiple query in the app.

Comment: So this solution may fit for you

Comment: @user3384231, no news about the problem?

Comment: all these days I asked the testing team to do the regression test on the problem. The work around was to create a list of all the possible unique keys that we may get and then we intend to use conditional aggregation. We have added a caveat that incase there is new key value pair then the customer needs to tell us in advance as the query won't capture new keys. So in short, just today its finalized to use conditional aggregation. Thank you for all your help.